# getting the values of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, c, opencv, scilab

I've program, in which I calcul the mean value of multiples frames, when I save this mean value wich is a frame I got a 965KB file, but I do the same thing with SCILAB which based on OpenCV I get a 5.93MB which sound more logical. anyway I decid to write my frame using fwrite and here what did:

```
 cv::Mat meanFrame= cv::Mat::zeros(height,width,CV_32FC3);
cv::Mat frameR;
FILE* inpR = NULL;
...... //after calculating the meanFrame
inpR = fopen("d:\\red.txt","wb+");
for(int row = 0; row < meanFrame.rows; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < meanFrame.cols; ++col) {
        std::cout << meanFrame.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[1] <<std::endl;
        std::cout << meanFrame.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[2] <<std::endl;
        fwrite(&resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row,col )[0],sizeof(float),1,inpR);
    }
}
fcloseall();
```

I can see the pf channel 1 and 2 but when I opencv the file red.txt  I get :

```
  €€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€<€€.......
```

any idea what I'm missing here, after that I want to load those file in SCILAB and than save the frame as file. 
thanks for your help!

Comment: You are writing 32bit IEEE 754 binary floating point values into a file (4 bytes per float), not a textual representation of the numbers. I don't know the file format, but it might use textual numbers, so you want to use an `ostream` on the file and stream the numbers into that (or convert them to strings by hand and write them into the file). If this is the case, you should also write delimiters (depends on the file formt specification).

Comment: @leemes thanks for your answer it did work with ostream, but I still don't understand the problem

Comment: What do you expect `fwrite` to do? You give it a data pointer and a size, the type information is lost on the way. A suitable alternative (if you insist on using `C` file IO) would be `fprintf`, the C++ equivalent of `fwrite` is `ostream::write`.

Comment: @filmor I tryied to use fprintf fprintf to get the formated so I can read it with SCILAB as a matrix 
      fprintf(inpR,"%lf\n",1,resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[0]);
it did work the file that get is formated but I only Zeros

Comment: That's because `fprintf` doesn't take a `count` parameter. You are trying to interpret a 32 bit integer (`1`) as a 64 bit double, you are lucky you made it out alive :). You could've changed the code to `fprintf(inpR, "%f\n", resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row, col)[0]);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the binary data - how a float is stored in memory.

When you view the file (in the editor or on the commandline) it thinks this is text data and is trying to interpret it as characters.

If you need to read this values into another program then you can use fwrite and fread (although you might have an issue with byte ordering if you have different CPUs)

If you just want to see the results, or want slightly more work to read them into another program, you can just print the values with

```
printf("%f", resultframe.at<cv::Vec3f>(row,col )[0]);
```